# jQuery - Got Questions About Animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm creating my own web site and i got questions on jQuery. Down below i wrote my jQuery code which is working properly.

When page is loaded text1, text2 and list show up on page. 6 seconds later they fade out.

Now, i want a new group of texts to show up after first group faded out and then i want second group to fade out and again first group to show up. I mean, some kind of loop. I'm new on jQuery so i couldn't figure it out.
 I'll be happy if you guys can help me. Thanks.

```
//jQuery
$( "#text1" ).load( "index.html", function() {
$("#text1").animate({right: 'toggle'}, 550).delay(6000).fadeOut();
});
$( "#text2" ).load( "index.html", function() {
$("#text2").animate({left: 'toggle'}, 550).delay(6000).fadeOut();
});
$( "#list" ).load( "index.html", function() {
$("#list").animate({right: 'toggle'}, 550).delay(6000).fadeOut();
});
```

Okay so, i tried setInterval() like this;

```
setInterval(function(){
$( "#basvuruyap" ).load( "index.html", function() {
$("#basvuruyap").fadeIn(870);
});
$( "#text1" ).load( "index.html", function() {
$("#text1").animate({right: 'toggle'}, 550).delay(6000).fadeOut();
});
$( "#text2" ).load( "index.html", function() {
$("#text2").animate({left: 'toggle'}, 550).delay(6000).fadeOut();
});
$( "#list" ).load( "index.html", function() {
$("#list").animate({right: 'toggle'}, 550).delay(6000).fadeOut();
});
});
```

As soon as this group fade out they repeat their animation instantly, i tried to delay it with delay() like this (did not work):

```
setInterval(function(){}).delay();
```

And then i tried like this (did not work as well):

```
setInterval(function(){}, 3000);
```

I need ideas to fix this. All i want to do is changing texts / backgrounds and doing it constantly and ordered (not a slider). If it is allowed, i can send here link of a web site that has the animation i am talking about.
By the way, i have another question to ask. I always use "" to code something. Is it a problem or doesn't matter?

Answer (score 0):

### Well, i cant write a full answer cause you are learning it, but here is what you need:

http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/

```
$(":animated").promise().done(function() {
    //Code here will be executed when all other animations are done
});
```

---

[setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds).

---

So all you need is using setInterval to call a function, wait for other animations to complete, then do the job. It's pretty easy.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i'll try it.